# Random Forest : Different specificity results between R and Python

Tags: python, r, statistics, random-forest

My problem is as following : I want make a binary prediction on medical data, with the constraint  to have 0 false negative -> I do not want to miss any positive observations.

The way I manage to do that is to get the predicted probability of the random forest, and to put a threshold equal to the minimum random forest probability of my positive observations in my training data.

With this threshold I can predict for everyone, and therefore get my confusion matrix. My senstivity is logically always 1, and the challenge is to optimize the RF to increase my specificity.

Now here is what grind my gears : I did my best to put the same model to the test in R and Python, I tried to set the same value for each parameter ; however my specificity got a 0.7 average difference between the two softs.

I use leave-one-out method to evaluate each observation and get the predict_proba (in python) or the votes (in R).

I add that I ran several times both models, we can observe quite a consistency in the results of both softs, and definitely a consistency in the difference between them.

I have a hard time understanding from where comes the difference.

Package used : Python scikit-learn random forest, R randomForest

Here are the two codes for the leave-one-out and the RFs :

"""

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

loo = LeaveOneOut()
loo.get_n_splits(X.index)

parametres = {'oob_score':False,
          'n_estimators':1500,
          'max_features':5, 
          'min_samples_leaf':5, 
          'max_leaf_nodes':50}
random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(**parametres)

y_score = []

# X is the dataFrame of my training data
# y is the dataFrame of my response variable

for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
   X_train, X_test, y_train = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index],y.iloc[train_index]
   random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
   y_score.append(random_forest.predict_proba(X_test)[0][1])
```

"""
Which leads me to the following results :

[537 257]

[0  64]

Senstivity :  1.0

Specificity :  0.6763224181360201

And

'''

```
# dw is the table with all my data
# param_opt_rf1 are my parameters : $classwt 1 1 ; $mtry 5 ; $ntree 1500 ; $nodesize 5 ; $maxnodes 50


n <- nrow(dw)
pred_loo_rf1=rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){ 
  id_test = i
  rf1 = do.call(randomForest, c(list(x = dw[-id_test,-c(1)], y = dw[-id_test,c(1)],
                                 xtest = dw[id_test,-c(1)], ytest = dw[id_test,c(1)]), param_opt_rf1))

 pred_loo_rf1[i] = rf1$test$votes[,2]
}

pr_loo_rf1=prediction(c(pred_loo_rf1,rep(0,nrow(d)-nrow(dw))), 
                  d[c(which(row.names(d)%in%row.names(dw)),
                      which(!row.names(d)%in%row.names(dw))), "y"])
perf_loo_rf1 <- performance(pr_loo_rf1,"tpr","fpr")

seuil_loo_rf1         <- min(pred_loo_rf1[which(dw$y==1)])
result_loo.rf1        <- ifelse(pred_loo_rf1 >= seuil_loo_rf1,1,0)



final_seuil_loo_rf1       <- max(pred_loo_rf1[which(result_loo.rf1==0)])

vp_loo_rf1 <- sum(pred_loo_rf1[dw$y == 1] > max(pred_loo_rf1[which(result_loo.rf1==0)]))
vn_loo_rf1 <- sum(pred_loo_rf1[dw$y == 0] < min(pred_loo_rf1[dw$y == 1])) + sum(d$ddi < 0.495)
fp_loo_rf1 <- sum(pred_loo_rf1[dw$y == 0] > max(pred_loo_rf1[which(result_loo.rf1==0)]))
fn_loo_rf1 <- sum(pred_loo_rf1[dw$y == 1] < min(pred_loo_rf1[dw$y == 1]))

table_loo_rf1 <- as.table(matrix(c(vp_loo_rf1,fp_loo_rf1,fn_loo_rf1,vn_loo_rf1), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

'''

Which leads me to the results :

589 205

0   64

specificity : 0.7418136

How can results be so different ?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you make two different runs of the R code or two different runs of the python code,  how well do the specificity values agree (R to R   or python to python)?

Comment: "Random forest" is less a model than a whole family of models -- there are all kinds of knobs and dials to spin. Different software implementations are almost certainly going to differ in results. It looks like you got results which are in the same neighborhood, and I think that's as good as it's going to get. I second the suggestion by G5W to look at run-to-run repeatability for each implementation too.

Comment: Stepping back a little, I would suggest that since you're working with medical data, and the number of cases is pretty small, work with a model which makes assumptions more obvious -- avoid RF or any black box. I know machine learning is all the rage these days, but frankly I can tell you from experience it's no cure-all. If you're interested in developing other models, my advice is to take your problem to stats.stackexchange.com for discussion.

Comment: @G5W Hi, specificity values do not change much between different runs in R and Python, which is why this is a struggle for me. In R it lies between 0,74 and 0,76 ; in Python between 0,65 and 0,68 (with various seeds). That's why I thought that this is not only a problem of the random part of the random forest, but a problem of implementation/hard coding, which I do not see.

Comment: @RobertDodier Hi thanks for your reply ; alright I hear you, but I find the difference too high (0,8 on a value between 0 and 1), especially with the reading of other comparison posts where results seems to be quite similar. I agree that this is probably a problem of implementation/hard coding but I did not find it, any idea to point me from where the difference comes is welcomed !

Comment: @RobertDodier I totally agree with you on this point and the bad trend to use ML whatever the situation. But three points : first these are not clinical studies, and the aim of my work is to find the "best promising" method, waiting for more data to come ; second this study had already been treated by classical statistics which gave not enough results ; third my interrogation is more about the difference and mistakes I could have made between my implementation in R and Python, it is more a technical question :)

Comment: If it's really necessary to determine the differences between R and Python, try one or more made-up data sets and see where the results diverge.

Comment: Good idea I will try on different datasets. But what do you suggest as protocol to see where the problem lies ? Do you see any mistakes that could lead to this difference in my codes ?